# Possible cause of unexpected shutdown?

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, crash

My computer has recently unexpectedly shut down with no apparent reason. The `last` command shows that the system crashed, but I was unable to find any reason for that in the system logs:

last output:

```
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-46-generi Thu Mar 28 10:02 - 10:22  (00:20)
username tty2         tty2             Thu Mar 28 08:39 - crash  (01:22)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-46-generi Thu Mar 28 08:39 - 10:22  (01:42)
```

syslog:

```
Mar 28 09:53:11 U-C-001 gdm-session-worker[1589]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available
Mar 28 09:53:11 U-C-001 kernel: [ 4453.744318] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Mar 28 09:53:14 U-C-001 gnome-software[2757]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
Mar 28 09:53:14 U-C-001 gnome-software[2757]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
Mar 28 09:53:14 U-C-001 gnome-shell[1675]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.75/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: /snap/firefox/198/bin/desktop-launch: line 174: /home/username/snap/firefox/common/.config/user-dirs.dirs: No such file or directory
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: cp: cannot create regular file '/home/username/snap/firefox/common/.config/': Not a directory
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: /snap/firefox/198/bin/desktop-launch: line 177: /home/username/snap/firefox/common/.config/user-dirs.dirs.md5sum: No such file or directory
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: /snap/firefox/198/bin/desktop-launch: line 177: /home/username/snap/firefox/common/.config/user-dirs.locale.md5sum: No such file or directory
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 kernel: [ 4458.808586] audit: type=1400 audit(1553763196.420:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/proc/6462/net/arp" pid=6462 comm=4C696E6B204D6F6E69746F72 requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: (firefox:6462): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_style_context: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: (firefox:6462): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_context_get_state: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: (firefox:6462): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_context_set_state: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: (firefox:6462): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_render_background: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: (firefox:6462): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_render_frame: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:53:16 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:53:17 U-C-001 gnome-shell[1675]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: activate: Error: Error invoking IBus.set_global_engine_async: Expected function for callback argument callback, got undefined#012setEngine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:207:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012activateInputSource@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:490:13#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012activate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:65:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_inputSourcesChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:620:13#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012reload@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:369:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_ibusSetContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:691:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_setContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:183:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Mar 28 09:53:17 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:53:18 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: message repeated 3 times: [ Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"]
Mar 28 09:53:29 U-C-001 gdm-session-worker[1589]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available
Mar 28 09:53:29 U-C-001 kernel: [ 4471.952558] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Mar 28 09:53:32 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:53:32 U-C-001 firefox_firefox.desktop[6462]: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Mar 28 09:54:45 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (4548485) is greater than comparison timestamp (4548484).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Mar 28 09:54:45 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: 0x1c00010 ([firefox website name]) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 4548485.  Working around...
Mar 28 09:54:46 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (4548515) is greater than comparison timestamp (4548514).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Mar 28 09:54:46 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: 0x1c00010 ([firefox website name]) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 4548515.  Working around...
Mar 28 09:54:49 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (4551614) is greater than comparison timestamp (4551613).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Mar 28 09:54:49 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: 0x1c00010 ([firefox website name]) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 4551614.  Working around...
Mar 28 09:54:52 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (4555028) is greater than comparison timestamp (4555027).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Mar 28 09:54:52 U-C-001 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1675]: Window manager warning: 0x1c00010 ([firefox website name]) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 4555028.  Working around...
Mar 28 09:59:39 U-C-001 kernel: [ 4841.893118] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=[MAC] SRC=[router internal IP] DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=15777 PROTO=2 
Mar 28 10:02:33 U-C-001 systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Mar 28 10:02:33 U-C-001 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x8e, date = 2018-03-24
Mar 28 10:02:33 U-C-001 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-038) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-46.49-generic 4.15.18)
```

Although there are several errors in the syslog, they all occurred several minutes before shutdown and seem to be unrelated to it. Is there any way to further investigate the issue? Do you have any idea about what could have caused the shutdown? I am running Ubuntu 18.04.02.

**Edit:**
Additional commands output moved from comments

ls -R /lib/modules/uname -r/kernel/ | grep noveau

```
nouveau
/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau:
nouveau.ko
```

ls -R /lib/modules/uname -r/kernel/ | grep nvidia

```
nvidia
/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/nvidia:
nvidia
/lib/modules/4.15.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia: 
nvidiafb.ko
```

**Edit 2:**
Additional commands output

modprobe nvidia

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available
```

lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1094
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

**Edit 3:** Additional commands output without disabling the SecureBoot

mokutil --sb-state

```
SecureBoot enabled
```

ls /sys/firmware/efi

```
config_table  esrt              fw_vendor  runtime-map  vars
efivars       fw_platform_size  runtime    systab
```

sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'

```
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
configuration: latency=0
```

Comment: You just obeserve the first line in the log `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available`. That means nvidia driver for GPU may not be loaded. Subeseqently `"Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`. GTK is widget toolkit for creating graphical user interfaces.  The `nvidia driver` won't get called for a given GPU if the `nouveau driver` has already claimed it. Is `nouveau` loaded? Issue this command: `ls -R /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/ | grep nouveau` and post the output.  In the command `uname -r` part should be in between "grave accents"

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "poweroff without any warning or logging" feature (who would want that?) However, your hardware does have such a feature.

Comment: Please post output of command:  "ls -R /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/ | grep nvidia". Please enclose `uname -r` in grave accents.

Comment: @user535733 Do you have any ideas how to determine which component was responsible if the cause was indeed the hardware failure?

Comment: Please add your output and other responses to your original question instead of burying them in comments. Comments are intended to help you  improve your question, not for conversation. Possible hardware failure causes is off-topic (we provide Ubuntu support, not hardware support), any search engine will answer that question readily for you.

Comment: Please @Magma, can you  post the output of these commands: 1) `sudo modprobe nvidia` and 2)  `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"`?

Comment: Command `modprobe nvidia` outputted `ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Required key not available`. This `modprobe: ERROR` has appeared twice in your log. This may result due to `secure boot` being turned `on` in your motherboard bios settings. If you want to use the `nvidia driver`, you will need to turn secure boot `off`. Please pay a visit to your BIOS setup screen and have a look!

Comment: Please @Magma, can you post the output of these three commands 1) `mokutil --sb-state` 2) `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` and 3) `sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'`

Comment: @Marmayogi Aplogies for the late response and thanks for helping me diagnose the issue, but I will probably attempt to sign the drivers first rather than turn off the secure boot as described in answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules). Hence the commands output above still shows only the driver for integrated graphics.

Comment: According to the output you posted, the following are proved: 1) Secured boot is enabled 2) You have EFI boot loader present 3) Intel driver is present whereas Nvidia driver is missing. Before attempting to sign drivers, my opinion is you, please, turn off secured boot.

Comment: **How to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed?** 1)     1. Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and issue the following command:`$ sudo mokutil --disable-validation`. 2. Enter a temporary password between 8 to 16 digits. (For example, `12345678`, we will use this password later). 3. Enter the same password again to confirm. 4. Reboot the system and press any key when you see the blue screen (MOK management) 5. Select Change **Secure Boot state**. 6. Enter the password you had selected in **Step 2** and press Enter. 7.Select `Yes` to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed. `continued in next comment`

Comment: 8. Press `Enter` key to finish the whole procedure. 9. To verify Secure Boot is disabled, issue the following command: `mokuutil –sb-state`. You must get output like: `SecureBoot disabled. Platform is in setup mode`. **Note-1:** To re-enable Secure Boot validation in shim, simply run: `$ sudo mokutil --enable-validation`. **Note-2:** `shim` is a trivial EFI application that, when run, attempts to open and execute another application.